# How do I stop Sass adding spaces before units of measurement?

Tags: css, sass

I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-responsive-site-week-typography-and-grids-part-2) on responsive layout design, but using SASS/SCSS as my base specification language.

To that end, I have defined the following SCSS:

```
body {
  font: 100%/1.5;
}

h1 {
  $h1_size: 24;
  font-size: ($h1_size / 16)em;
  line-height:(28 / $h1_size)em;
  margin-top: (24 / $h1_size)em;
}
```

Unfortunately, the output from `sass` into CSS format looks like this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5 em;
  line-height: 1.167 em;
  margin-top: 1 em;
}
```

— with the unit separated from the value by a space. Chrome rejects these values as invalid, and only uses them if I manually go and remove the spaces myself.

**Is there a way to fix this problem by tweaking my SCSS, or by passing an option to `sass`?**

So far, I have tried:

- placing the unit inside the calculation:

  - (`font-size: ($h1_size / 16em)` ) => *syntax error*
  - (`font-size: (($h1_size)em / 16)` => *`font-size: 24 em/16;`* which is the same problem I'm trying to fix

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can push the `em` into the `$h1_size` definition, which will let you simply divide by 16 and have a result in `ems`.

If both sides of the division are in `em`, your result will be unitless. You can easily multiply by `1em` to get your unit back, if needed.

```
h1 {
  $h1_size: 24em;
  font-size: ($h1_size / 16);
  line-height:(28em / $h1_size);
  margin-top: (24em / $h1_size * 1em);
}
```

Multiplying by `1em` can also make something closer to your original example work. You can generally keep things unitless, then only multiply by `1em` when you want the unit to appear. This avoids some of the pointless `em` proliferation in my first example:

```
h1 {
  $h1_size: 24;
  font-size: ($h1_size / 16 * 1em);
  line-height:(28 / $h1_size);
  margin-top: (24 / $h1_size * 1em);
}
```

Which way makes more sense mostly just depends on if your output will mostly be in one unit, or all sorts of different ones (including none).

Comment: Aha, you found the issue I just put in the update. Multiplying by 1em is a nice trick :)

Comment: I like the multiplying by 1em too. It feels mathematically correct.

Answer (score 34):

You can remove the space with a +

```
h1 {
  $h1_size: 24;
  font-size: ($h1_size / 16)+em;
  line-height:(28 / $h1_size)+em;
  margin-top: (24 / $h1_size)+em;
}
```

Will output.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.16667em;
  margin-top: 1em; }
```

Comment: Yep this is the correct way

Comment: I agree, you can do the interpolation way via #{$variable}em , but interpolation is not as simplified as this method is, which is what you are really looking for.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use string interpolation like so: #{$variable}em

Here is the reference: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Answer (score 2):

Put the em into the variable, so `$h1_size: 24em;`